# Error Paypal Invalid Request

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

estoy viendo un proyecto en laravel 5.6, cuando doy pagar con paypal tengo el siguiente error, estuve tratando de corregirlo, ingresando los valores que necesita manualmente es decir, los mismos de la documentacion, pero sigue saliendo el mismo error, alguien le ha pasado alguna vez esto. Gracias

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException thrown with message "Client error: `POST https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
    {"name":"INVALID_REQUEST","message":"Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema.","debug_id (truncated...)
"
```

Este es el codigo que tiene:

```
public function createSubscription($membershipId, $startTime)
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        
        return $this->makeRequest(
            'POST',
            '/v1/billing/subscriptions',
            [],
            [
                "plan_id" => $membershipId,
                "start_time" => $startTime,
                "subscriber" => [
                    "name" => [
                        "given_name" => $user->name, 
                        "surname" => $user->lastname 
                    ], 
                    "email_address" => $user->email 
                ], 
                "application_context" => [
                   "brand_name" => env('APP_NAME'),
                   "locale" => "es-PE",
                   "shipping_preference" => "NO_SHIPPING",
                   "user_action" => "SUBSCRIBE_NOW",
                   "payment_method" => [
                      "payer_selected" => "PAYPAL",
                      "payee_preferred" => "IMMEDIATE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED"
                   ],
                   "return_url" => route('payments.processing'), //Paypal doesn't accept underscores in the urls
                   "cancel_url" => route('payments.cancelled')
                ]
            ],
            [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                "Accept" => "application/json"
            ]
        );
    }
```

Comment: Lo ideal es que tu código sea texto y no imagen.